# Partitioning crown graphs into girth 6 diameter 3 subgraphs / packing of graphs representing finite projective planes

Tags: graph-theory, projective-geometry, bipartite-graphs, combinatorial-designs

I came up with this original conjecture several years ago, and the formal wording below about a year afterwards.

My conjecture:

**For all primes $P$, there exists a $P$-color edge coloring of the $2(P^2+P+1)$-vertex [crown graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_graph) with no monochromatic cycles of length 4.**

An equivalent conjecture which is not at all obviously equivalent (and is much harder to state, but is much more visual) is as follows:

For all primes $P$, a square checkerboard measuring $P^2+P+1$ units on a side may be colored with $P$ different colors (however, leaving all squares on the diagonal blanked out) such that no rectangle comprised of checkerboard squares shall have all four corners the same color.

I have only been able to demonstrate this for $P=2$ and have struggled to demonstrate it for $P=3$.  (I haven't attempted a computer-assisted proof.)  I feel that this conjecture is likely true, but I am not certain.

What I *do* know for certain (it's quite easy) is that for all primes $P$, it is possible to generate a $2(P^2+P+1)$-vertex bipartite graph such that each vertex has a degree of $P+1$ and there is no cycle of length 4.  Such a graph is equivalent to a single color subgraph of the conjectured graph type described by the bolded sentence above.

This is related to finite projective planes in some way, and even more closely related to [symmetric balanced incomplete block designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design#Symmetric_BIBDs) of which finite projective planes are only one type.  Also, the [Heawood Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heawood_graph) appears related as well.

I think an equivalent statement to the conjecture above is: For all primes $P$, the $2(P^2+P+1)$-vertex crown graph can be partitioned into $P$ subgraphs with [girth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#girth) 6, [radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#radius) 3, [diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#diameter) 3, [chromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Chromatic_number) 2.

Any one of these subgraphs is easy to generate.  It's partitioning the crown graph into them (and proving that it can be so partitioned) that is giving me difficulty.

**How can I set about proving or disproving this conjecture, or (if disproving it) characterizing the set of primes for which it *is* true?**

---

As pointed out by Paul Hudford in the comments, this can be restated as a graph packing problem.

Definition of "pack" (taken from [this PDF](http://www.math.iit.edu/~kaul/talks/GraphPackingTalk-UCF.pdf)):

> Let $G_i = (V_i, E_i)$ be graphs of order at most $n$, where $i= 1, . . . , k$.
>
> $G_1, . . . , G_k$ are said to **pack** if there exist injective mappings of the vertex sets into $[n]$, $V_i \rightarrow [n] ={1,2, . . . , n}$ such that the images of the edge sets do not intersect.

In layman's terms, given a bunch of graphs, if you can draw all the graphs using the *same* set of (unlabelled) nodes without ending up drawing any particular edge more than once, the graphs "pack."

My question involves taking a particular type of graph and counting how many times it can be packed with *itself*.

For any prime $P$, let $G_P$ be a graph representing the finite projective plane of order $P$.

In particular, let $G_P$ be a bipartite graph with $2(P^2 + P+1)$ vertices, where each vertex has degree $P+1$ and there is no cycle of length 4.  This represents a finite projective plane if one considers that the left-hand vertices represent points and the right-hand vertices represent lines; then the edges represent that a given line passes through a given point.

(Or to be more formal about it, call the left-hand vertices $L_1$ through $L_{P^2+P+1}$ to represent lines, and call the right-hand vertices $Q_1$ through $Q_{P^2+P+1}$ to represent points.  Then line $L_i$ passes through point $Q_j$ if and only if there is an edge connecting $L_i$ and $Q_j$.  Also note that since any two lines in a projective plane meet in one and only one point and any two points define a single line, likewise for any two nodes chosen on one side or the other of $G_P$, there is one and only one node to which they are both adjacent; hence no cycles of length 4.)

The question, then, is **for each prime $P$, how many instances of $G_P$ can be packed together?**

The *upper* limit is $P$ for any prime $P$ (simply by a count of edges).  However, it is unclear if this upper limit is actually *attainable* for any $P$ greater than $2$.

Comment: If you already know the type of graph you want to get for each color, then this seems to me more a packing-problem than a coloring problem. Have you looked in this direction ?

Comment: @PaulHudford, thank you, no I hadn't!  The conjecture could be restated as a packing problem, yes.  I don't see very much literature about graph packing, though.  Do you have any references that might help?

Comment: Very recently, Ringel's conjecture has been solved by two teams independently, [here][https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.02665] and [here][https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.09947]. It concerns tree-packing into complete graphs so it won't be directly applicable, but they do provide quite a lot of sources for further research.

Comment: @PaulHudford thanks; I've also edited the question to add the reformulation and also to make the connection to finite projective planes more explicit.

Comment: Ok thanks, note that your definition of graph from a projective plane is called an incidence graph, or a Levi graph. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_graph

Comment: wild guess, this could reduce to counting the number of isomorphism of the projective plane $PG(2,P)$, or maybe not isomorphism but some kind of "derangement" of your projective plane... I'll think about it

Comment: You should also have a look at the Ménage problem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_problem which also involves the crown graph. Your problem seems like a generalization to group of "n" peoples, rather than just couples, and also the Oberwolfach problem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberwolfach_problem

Comment: @PaulHudford, yes indeed, it's the Levi graph of a finite projective plane!  It's even mentioned in the article on [configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_(geometry)) that such a graph must have girth at least six.  Great to discover this terminology after I've been playing with this for so long.  I don't quite see how my problem is a generalization of the Menage problem to n-tuples rather than couples, but it does seem related, and the Oberwolfach problem even moreso; thanks very much for the pointers!

Comment: Stronger than *at least 6* : exactly 6. Even more A bipartite graph has diameter 3 and girth 6 **if and only if** it is the incidence of a (possibly degenerate) projective plane. These are even Moore graphs.

Comment: I recommand Anurag Bishnoi lecture note, especially chapter 5 : http://discretemath.imp.fu-berlin.de/DMIII-2019/